# How to comment multiple lines in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot find a way to comment and uncomment multiple lines of code in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Is it possible to comment and uncomment multiple lines in Visual Studio Code using some shortcut? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: How to comment multiple lines when one of the line is already commented html

Comment: **CTRL+K** creates a **-BREAKPOINT-**.  Breakpoints don't respond to CTRL+/ so highlight your code, **use CTRL+K to remove the breakpoint**; then press CTRL+/ to uncomment your block.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

First, select the lines you want to comment/uncomment (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is convenient to select a few lines)

Then:

- To toggle line comments, execute `editor.action.commentLine` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on Windows)

  **or**
- To add line comments, execute `editor.action.addCommentLine` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

  To remove line comments, execute `editor.action.removeCommentLine` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

  **or**
- To toggle a block comment, execute `editor.action.blockComment` (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>)

See the official doc : [**Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)

Comment: Sadly, `cmd+/` is not a valid shortcut for a German (Mac) keyboard.
FWIW: I changed it to `{ "key": "cmd+shift+7", "command": "editor.action.commentLine", "when": "editorTextFocus" }` to match Atom.

Comment: On mac, it's cmd+- (cmd and minus).

Comment: Weird, with me it's cmd+= (macos sierra and vscode 161)

Comment: I'm using it on js file. But it doesn't work for /* .. */ multiline comment. instead, it puts/removes '//' infront of all the lines selected

Comment: @Mario: I struggled for a long time, until I finally decides to move from my Swiss-German Layout to the US-Layout. The umlauts are the only Problem, but on Mac you get used to the "workaround" fast. The US Layout is the standard for (nearly) all programs, when it comes to shortcuts, so I would consider switching.

Comment: It is worth noting: if you have other key-binding/mapping extensions installed and enabled, they can interfere with the base VScode bindings. For example, I had the mapping extensions for Sublime Text enabled. Once I disabled it (cmd + / (mac)) worked for comments.

Comment: Using either the suggested, or comment blocking toggle `ctrl + shift + a` inside the grave-block in Angular template places either `//` or `/* */`, respectively.  Feature request for contextual comment blocking?

Comment: Thanks, `Shift + Alt + A` what i've been looking for

Comment: In some keyboards, its ctrl + ç

Comment: On a German keyboard for me, I used  `cmd + shift + /` and it worked.

Answer (score 835):

Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Linux: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

MacOS: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Here you can find all the keyboard shortcuts:

[Windows VSCode Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

[Linux VSCode Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)

PS: I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for toggling block comments because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is shortcut for toggling line comments so it's naturally easier to remember. To do so, just click on the settings icon in the bottom left of the screen and click 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and find "toggle block...". Then click and enter your desired combination.

Comment: This is probably not the top voted answer because of how VS Code works for different languages.  For python code, the "comment block" command **Alt + Shift + A** actually wraps the selected text in a multiline string, whereas **Ctrl + /** is the way to toggle any type of comment (including a "block" comment as asked here).

Comment: I found the suggestion to click on the settings icon and clicking Keyboard Shortcuts very helpful.

Comment: You can find the comment options in the Edit menu if you forget the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: **ctrl + shift + A** worked for me for adding multi-line comment.

Comment: Isn't there a way to add these to editor context menu? I'd like to add comment/uncomment commands to the context menu.

Comment: NOTE: keyboard shortcuts for comments do not appear to work until the file is saved - presumably because VSCode needs to know the file context to add the correct comment type. So none of these will work until you save the file...

Comment: CTRL + / works great for any commenting with the Vim emulator extension.

Comment: not working for me. What is your version of VS Code editor?

Comment: For whatever reason, in my VSCode 1.55.2, `Ctrl+Shift+/ ` nor `Ctrl+/ ` work. Though they're correctly set in the `Files >Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` menu. I had to manually change the keybinding. Now, `Toggle Line Comment` uses the keybinding of `Ctrl + NumPad_Divide` which is the same as `Ctrl+/`, but VSC seems to think otherwise. Probably the issue is somewhere in my system (W10), but this solution fixed it.

Comment: NOTE for Mac users: in general, shortcuts that are `Ctrl+Whatever` on Windows are `Command+Whatever` on Mac; In particular this is `Command+/` to toggle or `Command+K,Command+C` to add a layer of comments.

Comment: The URL for "All VSCode Shortcuts" is for windows. Mac users, the link is: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: Even I tried the solution and the comments here. One thing I missed here is Terraform extension needs to be added to get it work. After installing the extension for my use case, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 216):

How to comment out multiline / single line in VS Code:

---

### **MacOS:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>:

```
/* multiline    
   comment */
```

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
// single line comment
```

---

### **Windows:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>:

```
 /* multiline
    comment */
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
// single line comment
```

---

### **How to remap / change these shortcuts?**

**Windows:** File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

**MacOS:** Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

You can search through the list both by keybindings (key names) and command names.

---

**Read:** [**How to set shortcuts from another text editor (Sublime, Atom etc)?**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keymap-extensions)

**Official docs:** [**Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)

Comment: comment on remapping the settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676435/913098

Answer (score 113):

The keyboard shortcut to comment multiple in Windows is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: This one is better in some languages because it toggles "Block Comment". CTRL-/ toggles "Line Comment" which doesn't work in e.g. CSS or HTML.

Comment: How can I change this shortcut, I can't seem to find it in File > Preferences > Keyboard Shorcuts?

Comment: this is the only one that I was looking for. Simply because it's selection comment not whole line comment. It wraps the selection with `/**/` not the whole line. I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 57):

In my case, Ubuntu, the shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: in my ubuntu 16 does not work, strange, i can change keys but maybe depends on the file extension?

Comment: finally a shoutout for Linux in the 4th answer! works on 20.04

Comment: Works on Fedora too! Thank you for your comment, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> was not working for me!

Answer (score 42):

You can see all available keybindings on the official [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings).

Here's the relevant bit for osx:

```
Key     Command

⌘K ⌘C   Add Line Comment    
⌘K ⌘U   Remove Line Comment 
⌘/      Toggle Line Comment 
⇧⌥A     Toggle Block Comment
```

You will need to select the lines you want to comment first, then execute above shortcut, i.e. `⌘/` on osx `Ctrl/` on Windows.

Comment: But it doesn't talk about multiline comment.

Comment: @AmitGupta: ⌘/ Toggle Line Comment <-- this works for multiline too.

Comment: highlight multiple lines and ⌘K  then ⌘C or  ⌘K then  ⌘U will work.  ⌘/ also does the same thing. @AmitGupta

Answer (score 32):

Try option 1 first. If it doesn't work for you then try option 2 which is the actual shortcut for VS Code:

Option 1. <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Option 2. While the text is selected hit <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

As of now (version 1.16.3), you can check all available keyboard shortcuts by going into
***File  > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts***. Here you can search for shortcuts related to code comments.

For users who are coming from `Sublime Text` or likes to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, you can make the change from the above mentioned settings panel or simply install the `Sublime Text Keymap` extension by Microsoft.

Update: As VS Code has become pretty much standard editor for almost everything these days, I would say picking option 1 is always helpful.

Comment: Ctrl K + Ctrl U to uncomment

Answer (score 32):

In `MacOS` **comment out multi-lines** in Visual Studio Code by keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

```
/*
...
...
*/
```

Or,

Select all lines and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! This is MULTILINE commenting, while other suggest SINGLE LINE commenting for multilines.

Comment: how to undo it ?

Comment: my comment ```<!-- -->``` how to do like that ?

Answer (score 21):

For my keyboard layout it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>§</kbd> for:

```
//
//
//
```

And <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for:

```
/*
...
*/
```

Comment: Shift+Alt+A for mac OS

Answer (score 21):

For me to comment I use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

and to uncomment:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>

I am using `ubuntu 18.0.4`

Comment: This worked on my Windows box when working on files in WSL where WSL was running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17):

To comment multiple line on visual code use

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

To comment single line use

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! - [ctrl] + [/]  woks best for me to comment out multiple lines.

Comment: Using ubuntu on virtual machine, `left ctrl` + `/` worked.

Answer (score 14):

1. Select all line you want comments
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Seems a bit odd that vscode uses Shift+Alt+A for block comment when line comment is Ctrl+/. ReSharper uses Ctr+Alt+/ and Ctrl+Shift+/ for line and block comment respectively. For vscode one can see that the Shift-Alt-A keys (for block comment) are somewhat easier to press than typical three key combos but it's so non-intuitive as a keyboard shortcut. I configure ReSharper (could also do for regular Visual Studio) to use Ctrl+/ and Ctrl+Shift+/ for line and block comment respectively and vscode to use Ctrl+Shift+/ for block comment so that they are both the same and intuitive.

Answer (score 11):

All the key board shorcuts for VS code can be found in the link : [Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

- Add a Line comment Ctrl+K Ctrl+C
- Remove a line comment Ctrl+K Ctrl+U
- More shortcut Ctrl+/

Answer (score 10):

Win10 with French / English Keyboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> , <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> don't work.

Here's how it works:

> /* */  `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `A`
>
> //       `CTRL` + `É`

É key is next to right Shift.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for CSS multiline

- Ubuntu 16
- VSCode Version 1.17.2

Answer (score 9):

On Windows 10 you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> to comment/uncomment on any line or block of code.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For multiline commenting in **Python VSCode**, all you have to do it just:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

visual studio 2017 we do  a: Comment Selection

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to get shortcut. press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to confirm 
 http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Comment: For some reason I have trouble with this one. I usually have to press multiple times. CTRL + ALT + A works the best for me.

Comment: This one worked fine for me. A nice add-on to this answer is "How to uncomment".

Comment: to uncomment use `Ctrl` + `k`, `Ctrl` + `U`

Answer (score 7):

In the new version of VSCODE ( version 1.26.1)

[image: VSCODE Version]

1. Go to File > preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for `comment` Double click the existing shortcut 'keybinding`
3. And press the new keyboard shortcut in my case <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shfit</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

You can assign any shortcuts you want. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using VSCode in a linux environment, then you can comment multiple lines by either:

Selecting a block of code => then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Block commenting)

Or, selecting a block of code => then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (Single-line commenting applied to all selected lines)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the shortcut in the Edit menu :

> Edit > Toggle Block Comment  =>   Shift-Alt-A

Answer (score 5):

For me it was <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (I am using a swedish layout for the keyboard). Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: Same for Finnish layout, which is actually same as Swedish.

Answer (score 5):

For doing on mac: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Select lines which you want to Comment**

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> **to make selected lines comment**

[image]

**And to uncomment:**
*Select the commented lines you which want to uncomment*
First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>  then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>**to make commented lines uncomment**

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>         comment / uncomment multiple lines of code

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> for upper case latter

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> for lower case latter

Answer (score 4):

In windows you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> in mac you can do <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to make multiple comment

```
// public function index()
// {
//     $badgeIcon = BadgeIcon::all();
//     return $this->showAll($badgeIcon);
// }
```

Then if you want to un-comment then select the lines again and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>(in windows) again <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>(in mac).

Answer (score 4):

If your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> isn't working maybe you need to change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad_Divide</kbd>.

Comment: CTRL+/ worked for me in CentOS 7

Answer (score 3):

1.Select the text, Press Cntl + K, C to comment (Ctr+E+C )
2.Move the cursor to the first line after the delimiter // and before the Code text.
3.Press Alt + Shift and use arrow keys to make selection. ... 
4.Once the selection is done, press space bar to enter a single space.

Answer (score 3):

**CTRL + SHIFT + A**
For Red Hat,centos

- Select item
- then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For windows, the default key for multi-line comment is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

For windows, the default key for single line comment is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Multi-Line Comment in VS Code

To comment the code select the lines and hit:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

To Uncomment select the commented code and hit: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Keyboard shortcuts for VSCode on MacOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

I use **⌘/** to toggle commenting.

Answer (score 3):

To change the setting on VS2019:

`Tools->Options`

Search for `Keyboard`

Under `Show Commands Containing` search for `ToggleLineComment`

See what it is set to or change to whatever you like.

> VERY IMPORTANT: sometimes it is required to select `TextEditor` and not `Global`. this killed me for hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the existing shortcuts using the same steps as below. I find the default ones to be inconvenient, so I used the following process to change the IDE to use the '/' command seen in the comments.

You can customize the keyboard shortcuts by going int the "Tools" menu and selecting "Options". Then select "Keyboard" from the "Environment" branch. From there you can bind the Edit.CommentSelection and Edit.UncommentSelection commands to whichever keyboard shortcuts you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows

Select the lines you want to comment.
Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

on Windows 10, Italian Keyboard, VSC 1.19.1:

Select lines that you want comment and press "Ctrl + ù"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom shortcut here is the command name: **Toggle Block Comment**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my version of visual studio code and windows it is to insert """ in the following way

```
"""This is the code i want to comment out
over several lines
I want to comment it out
 """
```

or also the shourtcut `alt+shift+a`

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of an extension to the answer when the comment line is too long to fit on a line (above 80 chars or whatever). If the comment is too long and text needs to wrap, it's better to keep it under control (rather than use the editor's text wrap feature). This plugin Rewrap helps do just that https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap&ssr=false#review-details

Install the plugin in VS Code, select the text comment, comment it using one of the right methods described in the answers  (Ctrl + / is easiest) and then once it's commented, press Alt + Q and this will split the text to multiple lines and also comment it. Found it pretty useful. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

for add cltr + ù to comment , go to shortcut and search ctrl + shift + 7 (default comment enabled ) or search comment ,  right-click on shortcut > add shortcut key [ctrl + k ctrl + a ] ( is equivalent to aggiungi tasto di scelta rapida [ctrl + k ctrl+a ] ) , press the keys : ctrl + ù > enter .

should add a new line like this ( line above the one clicked ).
[image: vs code settings shorcut]

Answer (score 0):

For powershell it's `CTRL + #`. So basically, select your lines and use a combination of `CTRL +` the sign to comment of the code. PWS is #, C# is /.. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To define shortkey Ctrl + Alt + / to mutiplelines comment

Add this to your `keybindings.json` :

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_2",
    "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```