# Does Visual Studio Code have a comment menu item and/or shortcut keys?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does Visual Studio Code have a comment menu item and/or shortcut keys?

For example, I'm trying to comment out some code in a `component.ts`.
In VS I could normally just select the code and then click the "Comment" toolbar icon. But I don't see a way to do this in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to comment multiple lines in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316156/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Uncomment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>