# Multiline starred jsdoc-like comments in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to comment out my code in this style

```
/**
 * This is
 * A multiline comment
 */
```

Is it possible to do with a shortcut?

EDIT 1:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50301 Address this issue, however it does not work with a shortcut. I want to be able to select a block of code and comment it out in the style above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to comment multiple lines in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316156/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Configure the block comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822552/how-to-customize-comment-block-characters-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Thanks @quirimmo, but that does not solve my issue. You can only define the start and end characters of the comment. I need to add asterisk on every line

Answer (score 10):

How to comment out multiline/single line in VS Code:

- macOS:

  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Windows And Linux core:

  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

How to remap/change these shortcuts?

`Windows` : File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

`MacOS` : Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

You can search through the list both by keybindings (key names) and command names.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However VS Code block comments are in this style

/* 

*/

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is shift + alt + a (windows),
shift + option + a (mac)

Answer (score 2):

I use this type of comment in VS Code but I don't think there is an shortcut for this.
I usually do this by typing `/**`

Then JSDoc Comment is toggled and you can use that.

```
/**
 * This is
 * A multiline comment
 */
```

for more : [click here](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Yeah, but that uses different style comments /* */

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real solution, but you can make the `/* ... */` style comments with `Shift` + `Option/Alt` + `A`, and then use the vertical cursor select to insert a space and asterisk at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Select the bulk line list first, then hit below key strokes. You can reverse the operation by executing same.

```
Windows: Ctrl + /

Mac: Command + /
```

Comment: This add `//` but this is not what OP wanted: `/* * * * */`

Comment: May not be what the OP wanted but it was what I was looking for. +1 for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I made a keybinding to make these starred comment styles from a selection.  You will need an extension (that I wrote, full disclosure) - [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) - as it allows you to use javascript and/or the vscode extension api in the `replace`.

Make this keybinidng (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",                          // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "toggle starred block comments in selections",
    "preCommands": "expandLineSelection",
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const startRegex = /^\\s*\\/\\*\\*\\s*/m;",  // for /** start to block
        // "const startRegex = /^\\s*\\/\\*\\s*/m;",  // for /*  start to block
        "const endRegex   = /^\\s*\\*\\/\\s*?$/m;",
        
        "let lines = `${selectedText}`.split('\\n');",
        "if (lines.at(-1) === '') lines.splice(-1,1);",
        
        "const isReversed = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.isReversed;",
        // isReversed =  bottom-up selection
        
        "let firstLineNumber = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active.line;",        
        "if (!isReversed) firstLineNumber = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.anchor.line;",
        
        // get entire line of text - to far left
        "const firstLine = document.lineAt(firstLineNumber).text;",
        
        "const regex = /\\s*/g;",
        "const leadingSpaces = firstLine.match(regex)[0];",
        
        "if ( startRegex.test(lines[0]) && endRegex.test(lines.at(-1)) ) {",          // so have an entire block comment
          "lines.shift();",                                                           // remove first '/*'  or '/*' line
          "lines.splice(-1,1);",                                                      // remove last  ' */' line
          "return lines.flatMap(line => `${line.replace(' * ', '')}`).join('\\n') + `\\n`;",  // remove ' * ' from each line start
        "}",
        
        "else {",
          "let str = leadingSpaces + `/** \\n`;",        // for /** start to block
          // "let str = leadingSpaces + `/* \\n`;",      // for /* start to block
          
          "str += lines.flatMap(line => leadingSpaces + ` * ` + line.substring(leadingSpaces.length)).join('\\n');",
          "str += `\\n`;",
          "return str + leadingSpaces + ` */` + `\\n`;",
        "}",
          
      "}$$"
    ],
    "restrictFind": "selections",       // need this since there is no find
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
  // can use "when" clauses to restrict to certain languages
},
```

It is lengthy as it operates as a **toggle** - adding or removing the jsdoc-like comments.  And you can toggle multiple selections at the same time.

It uses the indentation of the first line within each selection.  You just need to select somewhere on the start line to somewhere on the ending line - see the demos.

The demos show the `/*` starting block characters, but see the code comments for changing to use `/**`.

[image: jsdoc starred comments toggle]

[image: multiple starred jsdoc comments toggle]

Let me know if you spot any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VSCode extension that appears to do what you're asking:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zachhardesty.jsdoc-comment-toggler

[image: selecting block of text, pressing Cmd+R Cmd+/ and it turns into JSDoc style comment]