# VS Code shortcut to add starred-block comments

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, comments, eslint

Is there a VS Code built-in shortcut or extension that will insert and correctly format starred-block comments, as described in [ESLint's rule "multiline-comment-style"](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/multiline-comment-style#enforce-a-particular-style-for-multiline-comments-multiline-comment-style)?

I am using TypeScript, but this should apply to vanilla JavaScript and other languages as well.

### Example

I should be able to highlight multiple uncommented lines as below:

```
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}
 
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
 
~~~~START HIGHLIGHT~~~~
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
 
cats.boris;
~~~~END HIGHLIGHT~~~~
```

And use a shortcut to comment all highlighted lines, so they look like this:

```
/* 
 * const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
 *   miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
 *   boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
 *   mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
 * };
 *
 * cats.boris;
 */
```

### Anti-examples

I am not looking for `Ctrl+/` aka `⌘+/`, which would yield:

```
// const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
//   miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
//   boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
//   mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
// };

// cats.boris;
```

I am not looking for `Shift+Alt+A` aka `Shift+⌥+A`, which would yield:

```
/* 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};

cats.boris;
 */
```

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545917/multiline-comments-in-vs-code to which the answers were only your anti-examples.  Seems like its not possible to configure.

Comment: @timothy If it is not possible with built in features, I am certain it is possible for an extension to do what I am describing. I am hopeful one exists that I am just not seeing

Comment: I have not been successful in finding one that does what you want so far.

Comment: Is it okay if the starred-block comment characters are flush left?

Comment: I just added an answer using your code examples to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76384378/836330.  See if it works for you.