# How to comment multiple lines with asterisk in front of each line in JavaScript in VScode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, comments

I know that I can comment with `shift + alt + A` or `ctrl + /`, but is there any way to comment like this with hotkey:

```
/* First line of comment
 * Second
 * Third
 */
```

Comment: Why would you want an asterisk in front of each line?

Comment: @Matthias: It's more efficient to see when having content section in front of the code file. Also in Better Comments extension in VScode, it's highlighted with green.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question but it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822552/how-to-customize-comment-block-characters-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: almost the exact same question but opening with `/**`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63545917/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You may try `eslint` as the only formatter in your VScode. It'll change your multi line comments to an ***starred-block comment*** on `save`.

Yet there is ***no shortcut*** to remove a ***starred-block comment*** in VScode that I know.

[vscode-eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

[eslint multiline-comment-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/multiline-comment-style)

Comment: Still no shortcut for uncommenting?