# VS Studio Code - multi-line commenting not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to comment out a big chunk of php. However none of the keyboard shortcuts, nor selecting Toggle Line Comment, or Toggle Block Comment does anything. They're not greyed out, it just doesn't do anything. Obviously I can manually add the slashes, but rather makes the IDE pointless.

Am I missing a setting? Or a plugin to do this rather basic action? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316156/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-in-visual-studio-code, You can highlight the code and then press Shift-Alt-A to comment.